# What is the syntax to use C# generics as a constructor name?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I've got a number of classes that inherit from `Item<T>`.

Each class has a Create() method that I would like to move up into `Item<T>`.

Yet the following code gets the error "**Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint**":

```
T item = new T(loadCode);
```

What is the **correction syntax** to do this?

```
public abstract class Item<T> : ItemBase
{

    public static T Create(string loadCode)
    {
        T item = new T(loadCode);

        if (!item.IsEmpty())
        {
            return item;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new CannotInstantiateException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible. You can only use `new()` constraint to force existence of a constructor.

A workaround is to take a `Func<InputType, T>` (`Func<string,T>` in your example) delegate as input parameter that'll create the object for us.

```
public static T Create(string loadCode, Func<string,T> construct)
{
    T item = construct(loadCode);

    if (!item.IsEmpty())
    {
        return item;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new CannotInstantiateException();
    }
}
```

and call it with: `Item<T>.Create("test", s => new T(s));`

Comment: isn't the OP simply asking how he can get that piece of code compiled without errors?

Comment: @activa: There's simply no way to make that work directly. The idea is fundamentally unsupported in C#.

Answer (score 3):

**Correction**: I made a slight mistake, you need another constraint on T for this solution, see code below.

You can only put a constraint on for parameterless constructor, but maybe something like this could work:

```
public interface ILoadable
{
    void Load(string loadCode);
}

public abstract class Item<T> : ItemBase
    where T : ILoadable, new()
{
    public static T Create(string loadCode)
    {
        T item = new T();
        item.Load(loadCode);

        if (!item.IsEmpty())
        {
            return item;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new CannotInstantiateException();
        }
    }
}
```

And then you implement the constructor code that depends on the `loadCode` in the override to `Load(...)` in the descendant classes.

Comment: But the compiler has no way of knowing that Load() exists on T. You'd need an additional constraint (an interface for example)

Comment: You are right... I got distracted by the wording of the question into thinking that T was of type Item<T>... duh.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work if `T` will be used as framework-provided classes, e.g. subclasses of `Exception`, which can only assign the property (i.e., their `Message`) in the constructor...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) to create the instance, although it does not do any compile-time checks.

Comment: The first idea doesn't work. A derived class can have a separate set of constructors. Activator.CreateInstance will work but it doesn't force anything at compile time so the code might perfectly compile and surprisingly fail at runtime which is not a good thing.

Comment: Right. It would have to call base(ItemBase), but the derived class itself wouldn't have to have that specific ctor. My fault, will change that.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the compiler cannot rely on the fact that the generic class T has anything other than the default constructor.

You can overcome this using reflection as follows:

```
ConstructorInfo c = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
T t = (T)c.Invoke(new object[] { loadCode });
```

As your T type must therefore have a constructor which takes a string then I would also restrict your class so that it must inherit from a class with a constructor:

```
class Item<T> : ItemBase where T : BaseClassWithConstructor
```

Comment: As I said in another comment, this works but is unsafe. And your restriction doesn't mean anything for a derived class. A base class will have a parameterless constructor and the derived classes might not have one.